# Golden Ratio To find Fibonacci Number

Tags: java, algorithm

I have to find the `Xth` Fibonacci Number i.e `F(X)%1000000007`
For Example If i have to fin`d X(350) = 672262724` . Here is a [Code](http://ideone.com/6DW5q6)
Now i am interested in finding using `Golden Ratio A=1.61 B=-0.61`

```
X(350) = (A^350-B^350+1)/Math.sqrt(5)
```

But How to take care of `Modulo`, as it is giving me wrong answer if i simply use `%` operation

Here is my Code:

```
public static double super_pow(double A , long B){

      double o=1;

      while(B>0){

          if((B&1)!=0) o*=A;

          A*=A;
          B/=2;
          o%=mod;
          A%=mod;
      }



      return (o+1)%mod;
}
```

I works fine when the answer is `less than` `Mod`.But for large value it is giving wrong answer.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work that way. You cannot pretend to work in a finite field and then divide by an irrational number, or rather you can, but it makes no sense. You'll just get some irrelevant irrational as result that has no relation to the answer you wanted. You'd have to do the entire thing in R if you go that way. That requires computing extremely large numbers and then taking a remainder, floating point numbers will run out of precision at some point and give you nonsense. The bit with weight 1 is always important if you're going to take a remainder like that, but it is not necessarily present in a floating point number, depending on the exponent. But perhaps you knew that, and that's why you chose not to do it.

You also cannot do this with finite field math in this case. Iff 5 is a quadratic residue in the field you're working in, this construction still works. A and B won't be phi and phibar, but (sqrt(5)+1)/2 and (1-sqrt(5))/2 respectively, which in finite field math will work out to "funny numbers" that look completely unrelated to phi and phibar (but are actually the finite field analogue of them). And of course, if you do this, there will be no `Math.sqrt` anywhere in your code. You need the number `x` such that `x * x = 5` *modulo something*, not a dyadic rational approximation of the solution among the reals.

The square root of 5 has to exist for any of this to work, but modulo 1000000007, 5 has no square root.

The following works modulo 1009: 856 * (627<sup>n</sup> - 383<sup>n</sup>)

Other algorithms still work, such as raising a specific 2x2 matrix to the nth power, and its slightly optimized version (avoiding redundant computation).